# Show Environment Variable while Debugging in Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, environment-variables, visual-studio-debugging

I would like to examine the contents of an environment variable while I am debugging a C++ program in visual studio.  Have googled lots but have not found the procedure to do so... any advice on how I can do this?  Thanks!

Comment: Have a break point in your application, run the application, when the debugger breaks, clcik the VS menu item Debug, select sub item Watch and and enter an expression such as Environment.NewLine then press Enter Key.

Comment: Sorry, should have stated language.  I'm debugging C++.  Under Watch, there are only Watch (1..4) subitems.  There is a QuickWatch, which is what I assumed you meant.  Entered Environment.NewLine but it told me "Environment.NewLine CXX0017: Error: symbol "Environment" not found".

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164891.aspx

Comment: I guess I am missing something.  I entered '$ENV' into the immediate, watch and quickwatch windows and receive only '  $ENV CXX0017: Error: symbol "ENV" not found'.

Comment: `$ENV` works for me in VS 2013 but not in VS 2010, where it seems to think `$ENV` (or `$env`) is an unsigned long with the value 2566.  Tested with a vanilla hello-world program in C++.  I don't have VS 2005 or 2008 installed anymore.  Perhaps those versions were just buggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the suggested methods worked for me... I do not know why (though I'm sure I was just missing something simple).  I wound up using Process Explorer to examine the environment for the process, gave me the info I required.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a watch that calls the C getenv function (e.g. `getenv("PATH")`) seems to work.